# C# Adding items of unknown types to an array/list/etc of a type inferred from an object type

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, types

I am having a tough time figuring out a way to add objects into an array without knowing the type of either object...so basically, we are populating objects using data we import from a text file. The objects we are populating will vary, we identify the objects using reflection to find the object with the same class type  as the string provided in the txt file. The string representation of the class is the ONLY knowledge of the class we have during the entire process. The issue occurs when we have objects that need to be created and then put into an array. I'm able to identify the array it belongs to fine, but storing the object in the collection is another story.

This is as far as I've gotten:

UPDATE:

```
public bool Populate(Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePairs, object obj) 
            {
                return obj.GetType() == typeof (Array) ? PopulateList(nameValuePairs, obj)  : PopulateObject(nameValuePairs, obj);
            }

private bool PopulateObject<T>(Dictionary<string, string> nameValuePairs, T obj) where T : new()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in nameValuePairs)
        {
            var itemName = kvp.Key;
            var value = kvp.Key;

            try
            {
                var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(itemName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                property?.SetValue(obj, value);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    var field = obj.GetType().GetField(itemName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    field?.SetValue(obj, value);
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool PopulateList<T>(Dictionary<string, string> itemProperties, List<T> list)
             where T : new()
    {
        var baseObj = new T();
        var lookup = new NameLookupHandler();

        Populate(itemProperties, baseObj);
        list.Add(baseObj);
        return true;
    }

private bool PopulateList(Dictionary<string, string> itemProperties, ref object list)
{
        Type baseType = list.GetType().GetElementType();
        var baseObj = Activator.CreateInstance(baseType);
        //Code here populates the object that will be added to the collection.


        return true;
}
```

Updated Method:

```
private bool PopulateList<T>(Dictionary<string, string> itemProperties, List<T> list)
                 where T : new()
        {
            var baseObj = new T();
            var lookup = new NameLookupHandler();

            Populate(itemProperties, baseObj);
            list.Add(baseObj);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not make it generic?

```
private bool PopulateList<T>(Dictionary<string, string> itemProperties, List<T> list)
                 where T : new();
{

        var baseObj = new T();
        //Code here populates the object that will be added to the collection.

        list.Add(baseObj); <--- This obviously doesn't work.
        return true;
}
```

Note that the `list` parameter does *not* need to be `ref` unless you're changing what `list` references.  It does not need to be `ref` to add items to the list.

Comment: Question 1 (follow up may be needed, depending on answer): This method is called from Populate. Populate determines whether the parameter "obj" it has been sent is a List, or if it's just an object. If it's an object it's sent off to PopulateObject, otherwise it's sent to PopulateList. Do I need to use 'ref' in the case of PopulateObject to ensure the object I sent originally is the one changed?

To clarify, PopulateObject sets the properties of "obj".

Comment: Unless you're changing which object `obj` _references_ ("points to") (whether it;s an array or a single object) there's no need to use `ref` in `PopulateList`.  If something that _calls_ `PopulateList` changes that references then it may be necessary to use `ref` somewhere up the chain, but not in this method.

Comment: @D Stanley Okay, cool. Now, when I try to call PopulateList as described, I'm getting the erorr "The type argument for method 'TransactionHandler.PopulateList<T>(Dictionary<string, string> List<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. But I don't know the types...

Comment: Did you change the last parameter type to `List<T>`?  It sounds like you may need two methods - one for populating a single object and one for populating a list.

Comment: I'm assuming that _somewhere_ up the calling chain you know what type you're dealing with.  You may need to bubble the generics up to that point.  If not, you may be stuck with reflection, which means that you need to call the `Add` method via reflection as well (since you can't cast).  Generics and reflection don't always mix well - sometimes you need to pick one or the other and deal with the consequences.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, although admittedly poorly worded the class type used is inferred from a string. We never know the class type.

Comment: OK I missed that point.  If you want to use generics to call methods on the collection you're going to have to construct the generic method call at some point.  Your other choice is to call `Add` using reflection.  Neither sounds very fun.

Comment: Okay, I definitely think in this case calling add using reflection is the way to go, simply because we have already incorporated it into the process. If you want to add that here as an answer I will gladly accept it.